# how to use vmware converter

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, vmdk, vmware-converter

how do I  use vmware converter? I've tried to search google but I can't find any tutorial on how to use it. 
I just wish to convert my xp installation to a vmware file so that I could use it on vm ware player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it for ages, but I seem to remember it being straightforward. You [download](http://www.vmware.com/download/converter/getconverter.html) the installer, install it on your system to be converted and run it.

Are you having any particular problems? If so give us some specific details and you may get some more useful help.